# Custom author-year bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I've been trying to create my own bibilography-style for some time now. In principle I managed it with a custom .bst-file, but it feels like a pain in the *** if you want to make a change or add new entry-types for example. For this reason I wanted to switch to Biblatex. The style that comes closest to the one I'd like to have is `authoryear-comp`. But there are some things I'd like to have different.

1. I would like to have the date at the end of a bibliography entry.
2. If there are multiple authors, the authors should still be listed with surname, first name and always be separated by a semicolon.

The bibilography in the example should look like this:

Boltzmann, Ludwig; Schrödinger, Erwin und Heisenberg, Werner: "This
is a long title of article B". In: Some Science Journal. 1970

Einstein, Albert: "This is a long title of pdhThesis A". Diss. Example School, p.42-125. 1950

Here is my current code. For compatibility with my old natbib `\citep{}`-citations  I use the natbib-key of biblatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleA,
title={This is a long title of article A},
author={Albert Einstein},
journal={Some scienece journal},
volume={1},
number={4},
pages={42--125},
year=1950,
publisher={Hellsevier}
}

@article{articleB,
title={This is a long title of article B},
author={Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger and Werner Heisenberg},
journal={Another science journal},
volume={42},
number={1},
pages={43--49},
year=1970,
publisher={Hellsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    style = authoryear-comp,
    maxcitenames = 3,
    maxbibnames = 5,
    sorting = nyt,
    natbib
]{biblatex}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test for citation \citep{articleA}. And here is another test \citep{articleB}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which produes

[image]

Comment: You can probably get away with very little for these. Use `citestyle = authoryear-comp,` and `bibstyle = authortitle,` for the first requirement and `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}` for the second.

Comment: Ah, and `\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}` for the third.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve these results with very little fiddling, using `biblatex`'s customization interface.

As to your requirement of having the date to the end of the entry in the bibliography, you could combine a different bibstyle to your chosen citation style in `biblatex`'s options. `bibstyle=authortitle` is not incompatible with `authoryear` (and variants) citation style. But notice that the differences between the two bibstyles are meant to make it easier to find an entry in the bibliography when cited with `authoryear` (the year gets close to the author, towards the beginning of the entry).

In case you do choose to use `bibstyle=authortitle`, you should also set the date to include the `dateextra` part (as well remembered by @moewe, in the comments), with:

```
\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdateextra}
```

For the desired changes in name lists, you can use:

```
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{articleA,
title={This is a long title of article A},
author={Albert Einstein},
journal={Some scienece journal},
volume={1},
number={4},
pages={42--125},
year=1950,
publisher={Hellsevier}
}

@article{articleB,
title={This is a long title of article B},
author={Ludwig Boltzmann and Erwin Schrödinger and Werner Heisenberg},
journal={Another science journal},
volume={42},
number={1},
pages={43--49},
year=1970,
publisher={Hellsevier}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    backend = biber,
    citestyle = authoryear-comp,
    bibstyle = authortitle,
    maxcitenames = 3,
    maxbibnames = 5,
    sorting = nyt,
    natbib
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdateextra}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test for citation \citep{articleA}. And here is another test \citep{articleB}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest something like `\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdateextra}` in addition in case there are several works by the same author from the same year. And I strongly agree that it would be better to have the year closer to the beginning of the entry (as in the `authoryear` bibliography styles) not least because that lets you handle dates with a finer precision than year more naturally.

Comment: The `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` should not be needed, I think (it was in the original MWE, but you should be able to simply drop it).

Comment: @moewe, Uff! I forgot `dateextra`, that must mean I'm rusty. Thanks! It's duly corrected.